# Find recommendations on similar album

Tags: gracenote

we're looking to use the Gracenote API to retrieve similar album from a seed album.

Example

Pearl Jam - Ten

You might like:

Soundgarden - Superunknown
Nirvana - Smell Like Teen Spirit 
etc

We'd need the cover art as well.

We're not looking at the audio player for now, just suggestion on similar album with cover art.

Do we have to use the Rythm API? Is not clear to me since in the website Gracenote talks only about radio station or similar.

Any suggestion idea would be very appreciated!

Best, 
F.

Comment: Yes, you can try with the Rythm api. Create a seed with that track and artist and use it to create either a recommandation or a radio... This will return a list of tracks that are similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you're asking by using the recommend method in the [Rhythm API](https://developer.gracenote.com/rhythm-api):

```
https://c*******.web.cddbp.net/webapi/json/1.0/radio/recommend?artist_name=pearl%20jam&max_tracks_per_artist=1&select_extended=cover&client=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&user=A_USER_ID
```

Here's what I get in the first 5 results (excluding Pearl Jam itself):

Nirvana - Nevermind

Soundgarden - Superunknown

Stone Temple Pilots - Purple

The Verve Pipe - Villains

By using select_extended=cover, you'll get a link to the cover art as well.

Comment: Hello Ching Wei, sorry just saw you replied also here. Thanks! All set and working =)